# ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."a.ear"."b.jar".component

Tags: java, eclipse, migration, jboss7.x

I migrated from Jboss 5 to 7.1.1 and on deploy I am getting this excpetion which is not allowing my ear to deploy and run.. Any help ?

Comment: you shoud post your log where it shows the stacktrace of the error

Answer (score 0):

This occurred because my Java JDK version in eclipse and my ear version is different.. I made a new build and updated my java version in eclipse also.. then it started working !! :)